# How to update existing Site Collections when updating the Web Template?

Tags: site-template

Just wondering if and how it is possible to ensure that already created/existing site collections get updated when the custom web template is updated which they are based on.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You have just discovered the major problem with declarative SharePoint solutions - the upgrade scenario.

Web Templates are like blueprints - you can change the blueprint all you want, but if you've already built houses off the old blueprint, they are going to stay the same.

Sorry to say, you are going to need to write code to ensure your old sites are brought up to the standard of the new web template.

Depending of the nature of the differences between the versions, this could be a simple undertaking or a massive headache.

Situations like this have contributed to the new direction from Microsoft in favor of the app model and programmatic provisioning over declarative WSP-based solutions.